# Magento 1.9 add a fixed product prefix

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite, product-urls, url-key

First of all, did quite some research, but could not find the best solution in this case.

For SEO reasons, we need to add a fixed prefix (with a slash) to all product URLs.

Product URLs now look like the following:

```
shopdomain.com/product-name.html
```

Expected result is to me URLs look like this:

```
shopdomain.com/car/product-name.html
```

Is there, by any chance, a standard Magento way for doing this? If not, what would be a possible workaround for this situation?

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: car is your category ??

Comment: No, it is not a category. It is just a type of product. There are multiple categories being used, so just assigning a class is not possible in the case.

Answer (score 0):

> Copy: /app/code/core/mage/catalog/model/url.php
>
> To: /app/code/local/mage/catalog/model/url.php
>
> replace **public function getProductRequestPath($product, $category)** with following

```
public function getProductRequestPath($product, $category)
{
    if ($product->getUrlKey() == '') {
        $urlKey = $this->getProductModel()->formatUrlKey($product->getName());
    } else {
        $urlKey = $this->getProductModel()->formatUrlKey($product->getUrlKey());
    }
    $storeId = $category->getStoreId();
    $suffix  = $this->getProductUrlSuffix($storeId);
    $idPath  = $this->generatePath('id', $product, $category);
    /**
     * Prepare product base request path
     */
    if ($category->getLevel() > 1) {
        // To ensure, that category has path either from attribute or generated now
        $this->_addCategoryUrlPath($category);
        $categoryUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlPath($category->getUrlPath(),
            false, $storeId);
        $requestPath = 'product-prefix/' .$categoryUrl . '/' . $urlKey;
    } else {
        $requestPath = 'product-prefix/' .$urlKey;
    }

    if (strlen($requestPath) > self::MAX_REQUEST_PATH_LENGTH + self::ALLOWED_REQUEST_PATH_OVERFLOW) {
        $requestPath = substr($requestPath, 0, self::MAX_REQUEST_PATH_LENGTH);
    }

    $this->_rewrite = null;
    /**
     * Check $requestPath should be unique
     */
    if (isset($this->_rewrites[$idPath])) {
        $this->_rewrite = $this->_rewrites[$idPath];
        $existingRequestPath = $this->_rewrites[$idPath]->getRequestPath();

        if ($existingRequestPath == $requestPath . $suffix) {
            return $existingRequestPath;
        }

        $existingRequestPath = preg_replace('/' . preg_quote($suffix, '/') . '$/', '', $existingRequestPath);
        /**
         * Check if existing request past can be used
         */
        if ($product->getUrlKey() == '' && !empty($requestPath)
            && strpos($existingRequestPath, $requestPath) === 0
        ) {
            $existingRequestPath = preg_replace(
                '/^' . preg_quote($requestPath, '/') . '/', '', $existingRequestPath
            );
            if (preg_match('#^-([0-9]+)$#i', $existingRequestPath)) {
                return $this->_rewrites[$idPath]->getRequestPath();
            }
        }

        $fullPath = $requestPath.$suffix;
        if ($this->_deleteOldTargetPath($fullPath, $idPath, $storeId)) {
            return $fullPath;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Check 2 variants: $requestPath and $requestPath . '-' . $productId
     */
    $validatedPath = $this->getResource()->checkRequestPaths(
        array($requestPath.$suffix, $requestPath.'-'.$product->getId().$suffix),
        $storeId
    );

    if ($validatedPath) {
        return $validatedPath;
    }
    /**
     * Use unique path generator
     */
    return $this->getUnusedPath($storeId, $requestPath.$suffix, $idPath);
}
```

> find **product-prefix** and replace it with your prefix.
>
> flush cache and reindex.